# How sqlite3 write capacity is calculated

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I create test table

```
create table if  not exists `HKDevice` (primaryID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,mac integer)
```

insert 1 row:

```
NSString *sql = @"insert into `HKDevice` (mac)values('0')";
int result = sqlite3_exec(_db, sql.UTF8String, NULL, NULL, &errorMesg);
```

disk report write 48kb
[image]

This is much bigger than I thought,I know integer size 4 Byte in sqlite,I think should be write total less than 10Byte.
the second write is also close to the size of the first,so I'm more confused......
Can someone tell me why?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing every row individually to the file would be inefficient for larger operations, so the database always reads and writes entire pages.

Your INSERT command need to modify at least three pages: the table data, the system table that contains the AUTOINCREMENT counter, and the database change counter in the database header.

To make the changes atomic even in the case of interruptions, the database needs to [save the old data of all changed pages in the rollback journal](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html). So that's six pages overall.

If you do not use an explicit transaction around both commands, every command is automatically wrapped into an automatic transaction, so you get these writes for both commands. That's twelve pages overall.

With the default page size of 4 KB, this is the amount of writes you've seen.
(Apparently, the writes for the file system metadata are not shown in the report.)

Answer (score 0):

There will be some metadata overhead involved. Firstly the database file will be created which must maintain the schema for the tables, indexes, sequences, custom functions etc. These all contribute to the disk space usage.

As an example, on Linux adding the database table that you define above to a new database results in a file of size 12288 bytes (12KB). If you more tables the space requirements will increase, as it does when you add data to the tables.

Furthermore, for efficiency reasons, databases typically write data to disk in `pages", i.e. a page (or block) of space is allocated and then written to. The page size will be selected to optimise I/O, for example 4096 bytes. So writing a single integer might require 4KB on disk if a new page is required. However, you will notice that writing a second integer will not consume any more space because there is sufficient space available in the existing page. Once the page becomes full a new page will be allocated, and the disk size could increase.

The above is a bit of a simplification. The strategies for database page allocation and management is a complicated subject. I'm sure that a search would find many resources with detailed information for SQLite.

Comment: actually,the second write is also close to the size of the first,so I'm more confused......

Comment: That's not what I experience. It takes 527 identical committed inserts into that table for the file size to change. It's highly dependent the  tuning of the DB engine which will undoubtedly be different across OS and environment. If your DB file increased by 48K bytes every write then I'd be concerned. Are you saying that that is what's happening?

Comment: In my project,sometime need insert or update more than 200~500 row in table,it will be write rate 5~10MB/s too fast make UI queue block one second.I want to more about sqlite write do thing

Comment: It seems that I have misunderstood your question. You are talking about data transfer rather than on disk space usage. I think that @CL's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49838924/21945) better addresses this issue.